# Hive: filter table by date of another table with matching key

Tags: hadoop, hive

I need to find pre-transplant height measurements.

**Height**

```
Pnt | Height | Date
001 |  10    | 'yyyy-mm-dd'
001 |  11    | 'yyyy-mm-dd'
002 |  15    | 'yyyy-mm-dd'
002 |  15    | 'yyyy-mm-dd'
003 |  08    | 'yyyy-mm-dd'
003 |  07    | 'yyyy-mm-dd'
```

**Liver**

```
Pnt |  Desc  |     Date
001 |  Liver | 'yyyy-mm-dd'
002 |  Liver | 'yyyy-mm-dd'
003 |  Liver | 'yyyy-mm-dd'
```

How can I select entire rows in table **Height** with height measurements taken before the transplant procedure date in **Liver** with respect to the Pnt key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you not join both tables on pnt and date comparison?

```
select h.* from height h 
inner join liver l on l.pnt=h.pnt and h.date < l.date
```

`h.date < l.date` - this should give you data for height measurements taken before the transplant procedure date.